# Chrome Bug? Switching input attr from 'password' to 'text' shows movement/bump

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am making a password field that switches from "Password" to "Text" when being used.  When the user is **using** the password field, the "masking" comes off of the password field and shows what they are typing (in italics - this is important).  This [temporary unmasking](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/password-masking-hurt-signup-form/) is part of a movement to destroy the confirm password field.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jqb9y8b/) to show my issue.

HTML

```
<div class="input-container input-container--text">
    <label for="input-password"><i class="fa fa-key fa-lg"></i><span>Password</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-password" name="input-password">
    <div class="message">A message goes here</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('focus', '.input-password', function(){
    $(this).attr('type', "text");
});  
$(document).on('blur', '.input-password', function(){
    $(this).attr('type', "password");
});
```

When the user focuses in the password field, it shows as text.  When the user unfocuses (blurs) from the password field, the field then changes attributes to `password` instead of `text`.

**Now here's the problem**.  If the user clicks on the password field again, you will notice a bump or movement in the field and the "icon" to the side of it.  This happens only in Chrome as far as I've noticed.

Is there a reason or a fix for this?

**UPDATE**

I've played around with more of the CSS and found the "issue".  This CSS:

```
.input-container:last-of-type {
    border-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:0;    
}
```

if I remove `padding-bottom:0;` I do not get the bumping anymore.  I'm not sure why yet since this shouldn't be touching the actual inputs.  If anyone has any insight, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found... That the CSS `top: 3px;` in `.input-container input {` *seems* to get lost...

I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/hn35oc8k/) and gave many border colors to elements to find where this "offset" was aplied or lost. I also gave an opacity to the `input`.

I confirm this happens in Chrome 51 and Opera 38.
**Not** in FF 47, IE 11, Safari 5.

You found a bug!!!
;)

NOTE: a fix would be to simply remove this `top: 3px;` from `.input-container input {` since your `label` already has a `top:5px` defined.

Comment: Great research! And awesome! Too bad their hacking prize money doesn't apply to bugs!

Comment: You should report it! https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en You can use my Fiddle and this SO question in reference... ;)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!  I will do!

Comment: It also works if you change the `top: 3px,` to `padding-top: 5px;` for example.

Comment: I suppose you try it in the other browsers mentionned... ;) Will you accept it as an anwer after ? ;)

Comment: Yes.. This is the top absolute position that seems to get lost. It certainly dont loose all properties !! lol

Comment: Also notice... The input width  in Safari is different than in the 4 others. ;) But maybe it's only a browser default css...